# MariaDB - What's the max blob size?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

MariaDB - What's the max blob size?

I've seen data exceed 64k on mysql databases. There has to be a higher cap, right? Configurable or otherwise or maybe a different data type?

Can anyone point me in the right direction or let me know if there is some workaround?

Comment: Hint: There's [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/longblob/) that sheds light on these otherwise dark mysteries.

Comment: While you can store 4GB in a column, MySQL really isn't the optimal solution for storing files.  So, always consider using a filesystem and storing the path in MySQL when applicable.

Answer (score 3):

MariaDB has a `LONGBLOB` type, which, according to the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/longblob/), can be as large as 4GB:

> A BLOB column with a maximum length of 4,294,967,295 bytes or 4GB (2^32 - 1). The effective maximum length of LONGBLOB columns depends on the configured [max_allowed_packet](https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/mdb/system-variables/max_allowed_packet/) size in the client/server protocol and available memory. Each LONGBLOB value is stored using a four-byte length prefix that indicates the number of bytes in the value.

Answer (score 2):

A `TINYBLOB` is limited to 255 bytes, but is no better than, and arguably worse than `VARBINARY(255)`.
A `BLOB` is, by definition, limited to 64K bytes.
A `MEDIUMBLOB` is, by definition, limited to 16M bytes.
Time provides the definition for `LONGBLOB`.